# How do I get the current mercurial revision without calling hg?

Tags: mercurial

In Git the current revision hash is stored in

```
.git/refs/heads/master
```

Is there an equivalent in Mercurial that doesn't require me making a call to hg log -l1? I know I can get the current branch in .hg/branch.

This is to "display" the current hg hash on screen when browsing a web page.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
$ hg parents --template="{node}\n"
52b8cee1e59c91b9147635b7f44a3a8896ee0b00

$ hexdump -n 20 -e '1/1 "%02x"' .hg/dirstate
52b8cee1e59c91b9147635b7f44a3a8896ee0b00
```

But why can't you just call `hg parents --template="{node}\n"`?

Comment: I'm impressed by your binary skills :)

Comment: Heh, I just opened up dirstate.py and noticed that the parent hashes were the first two twenty-byte sections of dirstate.py.  A bit of googling got me the proper hexdump formatting string (god those things are awful).

Answer (score 2):

`hg id --debug -i -r .`

Comment: The question asked "without calling hg"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a mercurial expert, but taking the sledgehammer approach and doing a grep for the current revision hash in .hg yields only one possible, and that is `.hg/branchheads.cache`.

I believe this caches all the heads of the repository, so it may have multiple entries. By default, I think it will always have two entries, one for the default branch and one for the tip revision number.

I think that branchheads.cache is rebuilt whenever new changesets arrive, so it should always have the correct current revision hash in it.

Comment: grep for the binary version :) (it's actually in `.hg/dirstate`)

Comment: Fair enough -- I should lock that sledgehammer away and engage brain.

Comment: The problem with this is that it shows the heads of the branch, and will be incorrect in displaying the current rev if you are not on a branch head. (via `hg up 3` if the tip and all other branchs are higher)